# Need to get Start Menu Paths in Java

Tags: java, windows-7, installation, windows-xp, admin

Using java, I would like some code that could get me the paths for:
1) Start Menu for Current User
2) Start Menu for All User

I need the answer for both WinXP and Win7. So hopefully there is a general answer that can get me both.

Comment: I would be cool with something like an environment variable like shown in: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I did not see any built in environment variables for this. However as a worse case work around, I might try to read registries (Reference: http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10150/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a solution, but maybe someone else has a more eligant one.

I plan on doing something like "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);" and the command will be a "reg query" to query the following registry keys:

Current User can referenced by: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Start Menu**

All users can be referenced by: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Common Start Menu**

These are the same for both Win7 and WinXP. If anyone else knows of a better solution, I'll be happy to look at it too.

Answer (score 4):

You have no other choice but to write a DLL and call native Windows API:

- [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAMS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, &szPathBuffer)`
- `SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, &szPathBuffer)`

If you really need the root of Start menu, use `CSIDL_STARTMENU` and `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU`.
The full list of known folders: [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you target Windows Vista and above, use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead of `SHGetFolderPath`.

You can use [JNA library](https://github.com/twall/jna#java-native-access-jna) to call native Windows API without writing native code yourself but pure Java code.

Comment: I like your approach Alexey, I probably would of went down this road if I didn't find the registry references.

Comment: You can get these values from registry, yet this API function is the *recommended* way of getting paths to special locations. It correcly handles redirected directories and roaming profiles. To read registry you have use Windows API anyway, and this function is simpler than registry API.

Answer (score 1):

In my program I used a simple `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Start Menu/Programs"` This gave me the user's Start Menu folder.

It worked on windows 7 and windows 10. I tried this because in order to get a user's desktop, all I had to do was call `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"`. SO I figured that it might work for the Start Menu as well, and seemed to have worked fine. I can delete and write files to the Start Menu just like I can with the desktop. Whether this is the right way to do something like this or not, I have no idea. But I'm just sharing what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is managing Start Menu items from vbs API.

I made a [Java Wrapper](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-utilities/tree/master/build) for that.

```
// Install Start Menu
WindowsUtils.installStartMenuItem(WindowsUtils.SPECIALFOLDER_Programs,"my_start_menu", "explorer.exe", "http://www.google.es","Acceso directo a google");

// Uninstall Start Menu
WindowsUtils.uninstallStartMenuItem(WindowsUtils.SPECIALFOLDER_Programs, "my_start_menu");
```

Comment: What versions of windows is this compatible with?

Comment: Hi @VenomFangs. So far it works for Windows XP, Windows 7. Windows 10 I am not sure 100%. If it doesn't work tell me so we can fix it, ok¿?

Answer (score 0):

i recently found this

```
public class VBSUtils {

  public static String SF_ALLUSERSDESKTOP    = "AllUsersDesktop";
  public static String SF_ALLUSERSSTARTMENU  = "AllUsersStartMenu";
  public static String SF_ALLUSERSPROGRAMS   = "AllUsersPrograms";
  public static String SF_ALLUSERSSTARTUP    = "AllUsersStartup";
  public static String SF_DESKTOP            = "Desktop";
  public static String SF_FAVORITES          = "Favorites";
  public static String SF_MYDOCUMENT         = "MyDocuments";
  public static String SF_PROGRAMS           = "Programs";
  public static String SF_RECENT             = "Recent";
  public static String SF_SENDTO             = "SendTo";
  public static String SF_STARTMENU          = "StartMenu";

  private VBSUtils() {  }

  public static String getSpecialFolder(String folder) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

        String vbs = "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\")\n"
                     + "wscript.echo WshShell.SpecialFolders(\"" + folder + "\")\n"
                     + "Set WSHShell = Nothing\n";

        fw.write(vbs);
        fw.close();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader
              (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        result = input.readLine();
        input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          System.out.println(VBSUtils.getSpecialFolder(VBSUtils.SF_ALLUSERSSTARTMENU));
        System.out.println(VBSUtils.getSpecialFolder(VBSUtils.SF_ALLUSERSDESKTOP));
        System.out.println(VBSUtils.getSpecialFolder(VBSUtils.SF_DESKTOP));
        System.out.println(VBSUtils.getSpecialFolder(VBSUtils.SF_PROGRAMS));
        //System.out.println(VBSUtils.getSpecialFolder(VBSUtils.SF_STARTUP));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know which versions of windows this works with?