# install4j packaged application requires administrator access to access disk on windows 7

Tags: java, installation, install4j

We are working on packaging Java 7 application for Windows using install4j.  The problem we are having is that on my Windows 7 computer I need to run the installed application as administrator for it to work properly.  It fails at the point in which it needs to access the disk.  If I run it as administrator, then it works fine.

Is there a way around this?  I have used other application that were packaged with install4j and access disk and I did not need to run as administrator, so I suspect what I want is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does you application do? The answer to this question is essential to resolve your issue. Does your application write to a system protected folder, like Program Files? If yes, then modify the application to store its data in a location where regular users have access to. Regular applications do not need administrator privileges to access files on disk.

Comment: Alexey, yes my app writes to Program Files.  I'll need to find somewhere to write to.  Is there a system propertiy that defines a directory that I can write to?

Comment: Writing to `Program Files` has been discouraged for a long time but nobody really cared until Vista introduced UAC. Where to write depends on the nature of data. In Windows you would store application data in user's profile, `AppData` directory. If data should be accessed by multiple users, `ProgramData` is a better candidate. Windows has API to get paths to these locations, yet Java does not. If the data is temporary, `Temp` directory is the right choice. To save preferences, use [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class.

Comment: By the way, it looks reference to `AppData` is stored in `APPDATA` environment variable for roaming data, and `LOCALAPPDATA` for local-only settings; and in `ProgramData` for machine-local settings. I'm not sure these variables are consistently set on every Windows system. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10662639/572834) for more info about the Win API.

Comment: Once again thanks a lot.  I signed up to your blog.

Comment: Just curious, what if you are doing reading raw data from disk (secondary disk) like what this open source VMFS drive does? - http://code.google.com/p/vmfs/ 

I know it requires you to open the command prompt as admin otherwise you get strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of application is it? Usually all applications are going to be installed in `C:\Program Files` folder. And probably install4j tries to install your application to the `C:\Program Files` folder.

Regular users (not admins) are not authorized to alter this directory neither create new folders there.

Is it necessary to install the application or it is enough to just wrap it in exe file to launch?

If installation is mandatory, i.e you need system folders, access to system dlls, then admin permissions are required and it is logical.

If you can omit installation and use a portable exe-file, then use an exe-wrapper for java applications. For instance - [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your response.  I think you hit the nail on the head.  i am installing it in program files and am writing to files in the installed directory.  so where can I put stored data?

Comment: To store data consider current user home folder, it can be obtained via [user.home](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm) system property. It is allowed to write to this directory without admin permissions. In windows user home folder for 'someuser' is: 'C:\Documents & Settings\someuser'. Create a folder into user home directory, let say 'C:\Documents & Settings\someuser\myapplication' and store your date there.